# html input with sharp edges

Tags: html, css, input

Can anyone give me any ideas how to achieve a html input that has pointed edge on it.

Something like this:

from:

```
 ________
|________|
```

To:

```
 _______
<_______>
```

Comment: Your best bet is probably to look into using either a background image or perhaps CSS3 [gradients](http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/). By combining the gradient syntax with the existing background color, you can often create edged effects. See also [here](http://lea.verou.me/css3-gradients/#intro).

Comment: @ChrisKrycho I started doing exactly that in an attempt to answer this question, but got a bit bored so someone else can continue where I left off.. http://jsfiddle.net/P89WD/

Comment: @adaam I think im gonna try your work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below are my contributions to adaam's work. I have the right arrow now fitting on the right side of the input box and aligned them a bit better.

HTML:

```
<div class="sharp"><input type="text" value="test"/></div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 140px;
}

div.sharp {
    height:30px;
    width:133px;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 30px;
}

div.sharp:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 20px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #000000 #000 #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}

div.sharp:after {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    right: -30px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 0 10px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #000;
    line-height: 0px;
    _border-color: #000000 #000 #000000 #000000;
    _filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Chroma(color='#000000');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P89WD/9/

Comment: That's pretty nice.. Now I am trying to turn that arrow to a transparent and borders only

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like [this](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).  Put a div on either side of the input box and form it into a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it through multiple images in input

```
input.yourClassname {
border-bottom: 1px solid #7e8ba4;
background-image: url(../css/images/inputBorderLeft.png), url(../css/images/inputBorderLeft.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom left, bottom right;
}
```